# Netsuite - Automating Deposit Creation

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I've just created a Suitelet to automate the application of deposit for Cash Sales where users will upload a list of Cash sales record in a CSV file and script will auto apply the deposit on cash sales and creates the deposit record, however I realized that there were simply too many cash sales records in the deposit record(>3000) to go through the list and apply them. This causes a suitescript timeout. I'm also unable to set a date range filter to the list of records. Are there any ways to achieve this without breaking the limit?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is:

> To keep it simple:
>
> 1) In the first request just upload file to file cabinet and return a success response
>
> 2) Then you would send subsequent regular AJAX calls to your suitelet to process
>   'N' rows, choose a viable number, preferably make following call only
>   after first has been processed. In these requests you should add URL params such as fileName to process and starting/ending row number of CSV file.

If you want, obviously you can optimise the performance by sending multiple concurrent subsequent requests as netsuite allows certain number of concurrent request per user session

In your suitlet you can use `request.getParameter(URL_PARAM_NAME)` to read a URL param value.

Comment: By AJAX call, I suppose you are suggesting to use nlapiRequestURL? Problem is that it will take quite some time to finish the whole operation. I've now tried a scheduled script and this also takes 20 minutes. If I were to use a suitelet, it may time out

Comment: That is why I suggested to specify start row and end row in the request.  Each suitelet call will create a few (N) of rows only. If you send multiple ajax in parallel file will be processed in parallel.  There is a limit on number of parallel request, probably 50 for suitelet

Comment: eg: lets say you have 100 records to create, you would fire 10 nlapiRequestURL() or AJAX for 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 ... 91-100 and one for file creation at the beginning, this will optimise time and execution limit both

Comment: I understand where you're coming from  but this is more on the time taken to complete the operation, less on the governance unit. If I were to use a suitelet and break it down to multiple requests also, it will still take 20 or more minutes to complete. The script will definitely time out by then.

Comment: i don't think so, it should time out if N is very low, there is no limit on how long client script can run, but, N should be low such that individual server side suitelet's response time is low and does not times out